# Cannot use \cite in longtable in tufte-book class

Tags: longtable, tufte-book

I am trying to use `\cite` inside longtable environment in tufte-book class but for some reason it doesn't work and behaves strangely. Using \cite in longtable gives several errors including `Missing number, treated as zero`, `Not in outer par mode` etc.

I get the following output in Overleaf:

[image: Strange behavior of \cite in longtable]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.05\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.55\textwidth}|}
\caption{Some  table caption} \\
\hline
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Column 1 Header} & \textbf{Column 2 Header} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Column 1 Header} & \textbf{Column 2 Header} \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\cellcolor{gray!25} \textbf{Heading 1}} \\
\hline
1 & Column 1\cite{article-minimal} & Column 2 \\
\hline
2 & Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\cellcolor{gray!25} \textbf{Heading 2}} \\
\hline
1 & Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\hline
2 & Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\cellcolor{gray!25} \textbf{Heading 3}} \\
\hline
1 & Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\hline
2 & Column 1 & Column 2
\end{longtable}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl.bib}

\end{document}
```

How can I use `\cite` inside longtable so that the references would normally appear in the side margin?

Comment: `tufte-book` do strange things to `\cite` that does not work in all cases, a simpler test might be `\mbox{\cite{article-minimal}}`, it gives a different error, but still give an error and does not with a normal cite.